# Lightning Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I have a Visualforce page in Lightning it works as expected. In the Visual Force Page I have a custom button that redirects a user to a standard page for edit. After the user clicks Save I dont want the user to be redirect to the original visualforce page. I want the user to be redirected to the newly created/edited record.

Visualforce

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!Clone}" value="Revise"/>
```

Controller: 
Part of the controller code... Its very long but at the end of the code, for the newly created record I am showing the newly created record in Edit mode.

```
 return new PageReference('/' + Clone.Id + '/e?nooverride=1');
```

After edit mode and they click save they are being redirected to my original page.... Can I redirect them to the newly created record? This works fine in Classic but not Lightning. I believe because Lightning the edit page is a Iframe?